# Remove unused css from multiple pages at the same time (whole website)

Tags: html, css, code-cleanup

I 've searched on google some online unused css removers that you have to pay. I also checked here on stackoverflow for programs that might do that. I only found an easy way via google chrome.

1. Customize and control google chrome
2. Tools
3. Developper options
4. Audits
5. Check Audit Present State , Web Page Performance only and then push RUN
6. Then i can see on the files the unused css of the current page

The thing is that this one does it for one page (current) only. 
I have a website with three pages here :  [PAGE 1](http://www.apolosiskos.co.uk/) , [PAGE 2](http://www.apolosiskos.co.uk/HTML-CSS_EDITOR/%5bB-Dat001%5d/) , [PAGE 3](http://www.apolosiskos.co.uk/SAMPLES). I want to find the unused css parts of all the three pages at the same time. Is there a tool or a website that does it for free ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try "Dust-Me Selectors" add-on for Firefox. It has the ability to crawl, even thru a given sitemap.

I also wish Google Audit had that feature.

Answer (score 2):

Opera has an open project Ucss. It's searching dublicated or no-used properities. 
[More here](https://github.com/operasoftware/ucss)